# Linking not working with `add_subdirectory`

Tags: cmake

I'm new to CMake and have the following problem (reduced to a MWE):

Given is the project structure

```
nlohmann_json/
CMakeLists.txt
Example.hpp
Example.cpp
main.cpp
```

The folder nlohmann_json is just a clone of [this repo](https://github.com/nlohmann/json).

Here's the content of the files:

```cpp
// Example.hpp
#ifndef EXAMPLE_HPP
#define EXAMPLE_HPP

#include <fstream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

void json_test();

#endif  // EXAMPLE_HPP
```

```cpp
// Example.cpp
#include "Example.hpp"

using nlohmann::json;

#include <fstream>

void json_test() {
    json jsonfile;
    jsonfile["foo"] = "bar";
    std::ofstream file("key.json");
    file << jsonfile;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "Example.hpp"

int main() {
    json_test();
    return 0;
}
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(MWE VERSION 0.1.0)

# Use C++17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(nlohmann_json)

add_library(Example STATIC Example.cpp Example.hpp)


add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Example)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE nlohmann_json)
```

Unfortunately, when building, I get

```
[build] /Users/klaus/Desktop/cmake_json_mwe2/Example.hpp:5:10: fatal error: 'nlohmann/json.hpp' file not found
[build] #include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
```

What am I missing here? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: It seems the error comes from compiling `Example` library. You code doesn't link that library with `nlohmann_json`.

Comment: Tto disable compiling the any stuff from dependent libraries except from what you exactly need, I suggest `add_subdirectory(nlohmann_json EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add 'nlohmann_json' as link target for your static lib:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(MWE VERSION 0.1.0)

# Use C++17
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_subdirectory(nlohmann_json)

add_library(Example STATIC Example.cpp Example.hpp)
target_link_libraries(Example PRIVATE nlohmann_json)

add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Example)
```

Also consider making the link target PUBLIC when you are exporting symbols or headers of the target.
In your example you are including the nlohmann/json.hpp in the Example.hpp. So everyone who builds against this header also need to know where nlohmann/json.hpp ist stored.

Comment: Thanks! It worked after making the link target PUBLIC.